# Plugin cycle2 não funciona quando utilizo api ().html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando eu faço a marcação no html funciona normalmente, quando escrevo em minha folha jQuery utilizando a api ().html não funciona, estou achando que é por causa das data- escritas na div, como eu poderia fazer funcionar?

```
$(function(){    
     $('.bl6-conteudo').html([ 
         '<div class="cycle-slideshow"', 
         'data-cycle-fx="fade"', 
         'data-cycle-timeout="240000"', 
         'data-cycle-slides="> .dicas"', 
         'data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2"', 
         'data-cycle-pager-template="">',
         '<div class="cycle-prev"></div>',
         '<div class="cycle-next"></div>',
         '<div class="cycle-caption"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d1 dicas"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d2 dicas"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d3 dicas"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d4 dicas"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d5 dicas"></div>',
         '<div class="bl6-d6 dicas"></div>',
         '</div>' 
     ].join(''));
})
```

Consegui resolver esse problema fazendo a chamada, na folha dos meus scripts, como disse o @LuizTanure e reinteirou o @FabricioMatte.

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).cycle();
```

E na folha do HTML ajeitei os scripts dessa forma:

```
<!-- jquery -->
```

// biblioteca jquery

```
                   <!-- Cycle2 -->
     <script src="js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script> // tem de ficar logo acima da chamada dependende

              <!--  Minha folha de scripts-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.meu.js"></script> // cycle2 depende dessa folha , pois tem partes do arquivo carregando nessa folha
```

Só assim foi possível fazer o plugim funcionar direito , quando inserido via .html() direto em minha folha de scripts (meu.js).

É preciso tomar cuidado com a ordem das chamadas.

@PauloRoberto Realmente não há problema algum inseri conteúdo via Jquery/javascript, só vejo vantagens, mesmo como string, na verdade além de ser mais fácil não encontrei contra indicações relevantes.  Veja ao inspecionar elemento que aparece como se estivesse inserido direto no html, além de ser fácil a edição, e o carregamento da página é rápido também.

vlw ;)

Comment: Acredito que é porque o cycle verifica a existência dos `.cycle-slideshow` e auto-inicializa-os *antes* do seu código que cria ele. Neste caso você pode chamar o `$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).cycle();` manualmente como o Luiz fez no fiddle da resposta dele. `=]`

Comment: Pode colocar mais código? Onde inicializa o `cicle()`?

Comment: Estou tentando Chamar mas não tá dando certo, vou continuar tentando. Sergio o cicle() inicializa na folha que baixei já pronta que integra o plugin, o resto é basicamente data- dentro da div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui e parece estar funcionando normalmente, mas parece que você esqueceu algo da navegação e talvez do css.

[Veja o teste no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/letanure/D2aZw/):

e parece estar faltando isso:

```
  '<div class=center>',
  '  <span class="prev"><a href=#><< Prev</a></span>',
  '  <span class="next" style="margin-left:20px"><a href=#>Next >></a></span>',
  '</div>',
```

Comment: vale falar que nao é boa idéia inserir conteúdo, html, via javascript

Comment: não há problemas em inserir conteúdo html em javascript, aliás é na minha opinião a melhor forma de inserir, porém não desta maneira como string, você deve criar os elementos

Comment: Percebi que ao acessar o site fica um pouco mais lento para fazer o carregamento das páginas; todavia, apenas 2 segundos a mais que o conteúdo inserido direto no html. Qual seria a melhor forma de inserir conteúdo no html, para conseguir editar todas as páginas ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Luiz, esse slide é só com texto. quando faço a marcação no html funciona normalmente, mas quando coloco como strings não. Estou inserindo todo o conteúdo compartilhado das segundas páginas de meu site, barra lateral, botões das redes sociais etc... para ficar mais fácil editá-los e mudá-los de posição quando necessário, usando esse método como strings no .html(), e o "algo da navegação" estão também como strings individuais para ficar mais fácil a edição.    
     $( '.bl6-d1' ).html( '<a href="#" target="_blank"> <p> texto vai aqui</p></a>' );

Comment: @Thiago, 2 segundos é MUITA coisa. cria uma pergunta que coloco uma explicação melhor. e não, não é recomendado inserir conteúdo via JS. mas é comum e todo mundo já precisou... é ver cada caso e não exagerar. Sem ver o código, dificulta, mas eu apostaria que o problema é a ordem. você inicia o plugin antes de inserir o HTML

Comment: Luiz, 2 segundos é o total para aparecer tudo na página, e quase tudo podendo editar e mudar de lugar via JS. Muito obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar. estou quase conseguindo chegar a uma solução, após sua resposta e dos demais amigos.

Comment: ótimo @Thiago, depois manda a solução/problema!
e se for usar muita coisa inserida via js, da uma olhada em templates engines compilados como .eco ou doT.js